# Benefit of LC tank circuit for signal generation?

Tags: passive-networks, coil

Suppose I want to drive an alternating current (100Hz, 200mApp) across an inductor to generate an electromagnetic field.  What are the benefits, if any, of using a capacitor in parallel to create an 'LC tank circuit'?

[image]

The two possible benefits I can think of:

1. Keeps more of the energy local (via capacitor storage), so that less current has to flow through the earlier part of the circuit.  For example, the output impedance of the current source may be 50 ohms, thus causing additional power dissipation.  However, the inductor resistance is fairly large (~100 ohms) in comparison to the inductance (50-100 mH), so it seems like the coil will dissipate power fairly quickly, and thus heavily 'damp' the LC oscillations.  I do not know how to quantify the damping or capacitive energy storage, though.
2. In case of a noisy driving signal, the LC filtering can suppress undesirable frequencies.  However, I expect to deliver a fairly clean signal/current to the inductor, so I don't forsee benefits analogous to a receiver LC circuit.

---

**Edit** After further consideration, I am going to say that there is negligible benefit of having a parallel capacitor in this case:

1. With regard to local energy storage, the LC tank can store at most (see [here](http://www.phys.ufl.edu/courses/phy2049/f07/lectures/2049_ch31A.pdf)) $$\frac{1}{2}LI_{max}^2 = \frac{1}{2}(.1)(.1)^2 = .0005$$ Joules.  On the other hand, the resistor will be burning power at the rate of $$I_{RMS}^2R = (\frac{.1}{\sqrt2})^2 100 = .5$$ J/s (or Watts).  I am not sure how to interpret the energy storage of the LC tank relative to the inductor's thermal dissipation, but it seems very small by comparison.
2. Any filtering effects would be largely diminished due to the large inductor resistance (and thus low Q or \$f_r / BW\$).  Specifically, it can be shown for this circuit (see [here](http://whites.sdsmt.edu/classes/ee322/class_notes/322Lecture6.pdf)) that $$Q = \frac{2\pi f_rL}{R} \approx .63 $$  This means that the half power bandwidth is ~160Hz, which extends from 20Hz to 180Hz and therefore is not very selective.

Comment: A *"current source having  source resistance of 50 ohms"* is more voltage source than current source. You're quite right that an inductor with 100 ohm resistance would be highly damped in your circuit. A reasonable inductor would have far less resistance than the current source's resistance. Then the circuit becomes an underdamped resonator. And you now get benefits: a small exciting current builds far larger currents that toggle back-and-forth between L and C.

Comment: Your driver does not need to be overly powerful to build up large circulating currents in the LC tank. A jellybean opamp may pump up an LC tank into the several amps rms.

Comment: Actually, I realized that in order to reduce the voltage necessary to provide a given current, it may be beneficial to use a capacitor in series to negate any inductive reactance.  Alternatively, both a series and parallel capacitor may be used as shown in http://www.electronicdesign.com/analog/resonant-circuit-generates-high-frequency-magnetic-field, though it recommends this for low-R inductors only.